# What should the tag be for "The Following Events Are Based on a Pack of Lies"?

Tags: discussion, tags

The title of the TV series ["The Following Events Are Based on a Pack of Lies"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12966558/) is too long for a tag: it has 48 characters, when the maximum tag length is 35.

- A possible tag could be [events-are-based-on-a-pack-of-lies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events-are-based-on-a-pack-of-lies) (34 characters), but that would mean this tag would not show up if they start typing "the following...". Perhaps this tag could be coupled with another tag: [the-following-events-are-based](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-following-events-are-based).
- Another possibility is to only use the "important" words from the title: [following-events-based-pack-lies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/following-events-based-pack-lies) (32 characters).
- Or perhaps a combination of the above: [following-events-based-pack-lies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/following-events-based-pack-lies) as the one that is displayed, and the other two as duplicates?

Yes, we do have a question about this show: [Based on a Pack of Lies (2023) Judaism connection](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/122093/based-on-a-pack-of-lies-2023-judaism-connection)

Comment: I don't know the film, but although it leaves away the most words from all the options, I think `based-on-a-pack-of-lies` like the question title actually does, is a viable alternative too. It sounds the most intuitive as an abbreviation of the title.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Sounds like it should be an answer. I'd support it.

Comment: That said, the question is likely to be closed shortly and the tag will probably age away